# What is wrong with my method of reversing a .wav file with 2 channels in C

Tags: c, file-io, cs50, wav

check50 failed to pass (reverse.c reverses ascending scale file is not reversed as specified). The sound seems reversed but check50 failed to pass.

For any sampleFrame, I split it into left and right channels respectively, writing the right channel, then left, in that order. I also tried the opposite (left channel, then right channel) and check50 also failed.

The last `fseek()` call uses var i to adjust the pointer to the last unread sampleFrame, so that at each iteration the `fread` only has one block to read so long as nBlocks is not 0.

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "wav.h"

const int HEADERSIZE = 44;

bool check_format(WAVHEADER header);
int get_block_size(WAVHEADER header);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // #1 Ensure proper usage
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        printf("usage: reverse input.wav output.wav\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // #2 Open input file for reading
    FILE *input = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if (input == NULL)
    {
        printf("error opening input file!\n");
        return 2;
    }
    
    // #3 Read header(of type struct WAVHEADER) from input file
    WAVHEADER header;
    fread(&header, sizeof(header), 1, input);
    
    // #4 Use check_format to ensure WAV format
    int fileFormat = check_format(header);
    
    // #5 Open output file for writing
    FILE *output = fopen(argv[2], "wb");
    if (output == NULL)
    {
        printf("error opening output file!\n");
        return 3;
    }

    // #6 Write header to file
    fwrite(&header, sizeof(header), 1, output);

    // #7 Use get_block_size() to calculate size of block
    int blockSize = get_block_size(header);
    
    // calculate number of blocks in a WAv file
    int nBlocks;
    fseek(input, 0, SEEK_END);
    nBlocks = (ftell(input) - HEADERSIZE) / blockSize;
     
    // #8 Write reversed audio to file
    // declare array to store each block we read-in
    // type array[size] to hold blockAlign or audio block
    BYTE sampleFrame[blockSize];
    
    // seek pointer to lasst blockSize of input file
    fseek(input, -blockSize - 1, SEEK_END);
    
    int i = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < nBlocks; i++)
    {
        // read audioBlock from input file
        fread(sampleFrame, sizeof(BYTE), blockSize, input);
        
        // write it to the output file
        fwrite(sampleFrame, sizeof(BYTE), blockSize, output);
        
        // adjust fseek call to start at next unread sampleFrame
        fseek(input, (-i * blockSize), SEEK_END);
        
    }    
    // #9 close opened files
    fclose(output);
    fclose(input);
}

bool check_format(WAVHEADER header)
{
    // check correct wav format and return TRUE    
    char format[4];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        format[i] = header.format[i];
    }    
    
    if (strcmp(format, "WAVE") == 0)
    {
        // return true:1
        return true;
    }
    // else return false:0 ?
    return false;    
}

int get_block_size(WAVHEADER header)
{
    // printf("channels: %i, bps: %i\n", header.numChannels, (header.bitsPerSample / 8));

    int blockSize = header.numChannels * (header.bitsPerSample / 8); // => byte;
    return blockSize;
}
```

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: You have `fseek(input, (-i * blockSize), SEEK_END);` ready for the next loop, and some stuff which messes with `i` and the loop counter. If you know how many blocks there are: use that in a `for` loop, and then set the next file pointer with `fseek(input, -2 * blockSize, SEEK_CUR);` ready for the next loop.

Comment: You don't need to reset the file pointer to the beginning of the file with `fseek(input, 0, SEEK_SET);` because you already read the header and next you move to the end of the file (minus 1 block).

Comment: @WeatherVane i got that, but is the reversing OK?

Comment: I thought the point of the question is that it isn't. Do they really require you to reverse the left/right channel too? I don't get why you need all the in-loop `malloc` and `free`. Read the block, then write the block.

Comment: from all indications yes, because i tried writing the sampleFrames to output as i read them from the last blockAlign, the sound seems reversed but check50 failed. thats why i split the channels into two to see if that might work according to what i learned from https://medium.com/swlh/reversing-a-wav-file-in-c-482fc3dfe3c4

Comment: I haven't looked at the CS50 problem statement but you can find other questions here about the problem. I don't recall them swapping the channls, only the sequence.

Comment: thanks sir, i will try that then ...@WeatherVane

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256014/discussion-between-abuaminu-and-weather-vane).

Comment: One basic check to make is that the output file is the same size as the input file.

Comment: i think i solved it, their test requires use of ftell() as while loop variable  or use for loop for i = blockSize - 1 to i >= 0 as its condition. thanks alot for the support @weathervane